# Can't add item to listview

Tags: c#, .net

I made a c# project that lists certain things in `ListViews`, but the `ListViews`are a little annoying, they don't work everytime, sometimes the input is correct and can be displayed in a `MessageBox` or `ListBox` but nothing happens when trying to add it to the `ListBox`, this is my code right now and nothing happens when pressing the button.

```
 private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if(shouldirefresh == true)
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
            checkBox1.Enabled = false;
            checkBox2.Enabled = false;
            checkBox3.Enabled = false;
            checkBox4.Enabled = false;
            checkBox5.Enabled = false;
            checkBox6.Enabled = false;
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
            await td(3500);
        }


        checkBox1.Text = "Highlight -50%";
        checkBox2.Text = "Highlight 100%";
        checkBox3.Text = "Highlight 50%";
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        min50 = 0;
        max100 = 0;
        eq50 = 0;
        listView1.Items.Clear(); 
        listBox1.Items.Clear(); listBox2.Items.Clear(); listBox3.Items.Clear(); listBox4.Items.Clear();
        lsttit.Clear(); lstpoint.Clear(); lstmaxwosl.Clear(); lstmax.Clear();
        HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
        doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        var links = PulseVar.myrodoc.GetElementsByTagName("td");
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {


            if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "title")
            {

                lsttit.Add(link.InnerText);

            }
            else if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "point" || link.GetAttribute("className") == "point tekort")
            {
                lstpoint.Add(link.InnerText);
            }
            else if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "max" || link.GetAttribute("className") == "max tekort")
            {
                string RM = link.InnerText.Remove(0, 1);
                lstmax.Add(RM);
            }
            else if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "date")
            {
                datez.Add(link.InnerText);
            }
           else if(link.GetAttribute("className") == "average")
            {

                lstav.Add(link.InnerText);

            }
            else if(link.GetAttribute("className") == "comment")
            {
                if(link.InnerText == "&nbsp")
                {
                    lstcomment.Add("  ");
                }
                else
                {
                    lstcomment.Add(link.InnerText);
                }
            }
            else if(link.GetAttribute("className") == "TeacherTitle")
            {
                this.Text = "Myro ~ " + link.InnerText;

            }


        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= lsttit.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            ListViewItem d = new ListViewItem(lsttit[i]);

            try
            {
                if (decimal.Parse(lstpoint[i]) < (decimal.Parse(lstmax[i]) / 2))
                {

                    min50++;

                    d.SubItems.Add(lstpoint[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);

                    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
                    {
                        d.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
                else if (decimal.Parse(lstpoint[i]) == (decimal.Parse(lstmax[i])))
                {
                    //listView2.Items.Add(lstpoint[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);
                    d.SubItems.Add(lstpoint[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);
                    if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
                    {
                        d.ForeColor = Color.Green;

                    }
                    max100++;

                }
                else if (decimal.Parse(lstpoint[i]) == (decimal.Parse(lstmax[i]) / 2))
                {
                    //listView2.Items.Add(lstpoint[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);
                    d.SubItems.Add(lstpoint[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);
                    if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
                    {
                        d.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                    }
                    eq50++;
                }
                else
                {
                    d.SubItems.Add(lstpoint[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);
                    //listView2.Items.Add(lstpoint[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //listView2.Items.Add(lstpoint[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);
                d.SubItems.Add(lstpoint[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);
            }
            d.SubItems.Add(datez[i]);
            d.SubItems.Add(lstav[i] + "/" + lstmax[i]);
            d.SubItems.Add(lstcomment[i]);
            listView1.Items.Add(d);
        }
        checkBox1.Text += "(" + min50.ToString() + ")";
        checkBox2.Text += "(" + max100.ToString() + ")";
        checkBox3.Text += "(" + eq50.ToString() + ")";

        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        //groupBox1.Location = new Point(12, 12);
        checkBox5.Checked = false;


        button2.Enabled = true;
        checkBox1.Enabled = true;
        checkBox2.Enabled = true;
        checkBox3.Enabled = true;
        checkBox4.Enabled = true;
        checkBox5.Enabled = true;
        checkBox6.Enabled = true;
        shouldirefresh = true;
        label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");


   }
```

Again if I do `MessageBox.Show(lsttit[i]);` it shows the correct data everytime, my `ListView` has the correct columns and is set to details but nothing happens at all....

what's wrong here?

Comment: `"nothing happens when pressing the button"` - What button?  If "nothing happens" when pressing a button then the button has no click handler attached to it, which has nothing to do with the code posted in the question.  When you step through this in a debugger, what *does* happen?  Where does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?

Comment: Where are you adding the `ListViewItem` to the `ListView`?

Comment: Post the whole function. There is no code there to add the item to the list.

Comment: it's at the end of the for loop... again it works and sometimes it doesnt

Comment: Well then please show it to us. Always show the whole code which is relevant when asking a question. Else we cannot help you completely if we only see the half code :)

Comment: Just added the whole code for the button

Comment: When nothing happens when presing the button, try debugging the code, add breakpoints to places where something is expected to happen, like the lines where items are added to the lists, just to check the code goes thruugh there.

Comment: Have you really added all necessary `Columns`? 

You can add `SubItems` but without `Columns` 'nothing will display'..